# Why RegexOptions are compiled to RegexOptions.None in MSIL?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, il

This code

```
  Regex regex = new Regex("blah", RegexOptions.Singleline & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

after compilation looks like this in ILSpy:

```
  Regex regex = new Regex("blah", RegexOptions.None);
```

Why does it happen and can it be the reason of regex not matching in .Net 3.5? On 4.5 it works.

Comment: Don't you mean `RegexOptions.SingleLine | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, i.e. a bitwise _or_ instead of _and_? Presumably the options are flags (powers of two) so bitwise and of any two of them will give zero (which, converted back to an enum value, is `None`).

Comment: Yes, that done the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
RegexOptions.Singleline & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

is a bitwise AND, and resolves to 0 (i.e. `RegexOptions.None`).

The `RegexOptions` enum looks like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum RegexOptions
{
    None = 0,
    IgnoreCase = 1,
    Multiline = 2,
    ExplicitCapture = 4,
    Compiled = 8,
    Singleline = 16,
    IgnorePatternWhitespace = 32,
    RightToLeft = 64,
    ECMAScript = 256,
    CultureInvariant = 512,
}
```

So, in binary, we have:

```
RegexOptions.SingleLine == 10000 
RegexOptions.IngoreCase == 00001
```

When applying a bitwise AND, we get :

```
    10000 
AND 00001
    -----
    00000
```

Replace with

```
RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

which gives:

```
    10000 
 OR 00001
    -----
    10001
```

That ILSpy will decompile in:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("blah", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But I don't know what "works" in .Net 4.5. I just compiled your code, and ILSpy also outputs:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("blah", RegexOptions.None);
```

as intended.

Comment: Someday I will learn how to combine flags correctly. Thank you.

Regarding .Net 4.5, I do confirm that the same regex on the same text matches on my dev machine as if singleline option was specified correctly, but will fail to match on XP (same assembly, no debugger, release compilation).  Basically, this is what confused me in the first place.

Comment: Most probably it was incorrect testing as I cannot reproduce the issue on the clean project.